# How can I default category through API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

I have written a project which receives data through an API. Clicking on each button displays corresponding news. For example, when you press the sports button, sports news comes. However, I want the All category to be active when the page is first opened. In other words, those news should have arrived without pressing the all button. How can I do this?

Not - The function inside `useEffect` returns every time it renders and it doesn't work for me. For example, when you refresh the page while reading sports news, all news comes:

```html
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import SpinnerLoad from './components/SpinnerLoad'
import NewsItem from "./components/NewsItem";
import Category from "./components/data/Category"
const App = () => {

  const [state, setState] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)


  const fetchValue = (category) => {
    fetch(`https://inshorts-api.herokuapp.com/news?category=${category}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        setState(res.data)
        setLoading(true)
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error))
      setLoading(false);
  };

  const CategoryButton = ({ category }) => (
    <button onClick={() => fetchValue(category)} style={{ textTransform: 'capitalize' }}>{category}</button>
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchValue('all')
  }, [])

  return (
    <>

      <div className="header-bg">
        <h1 className="mb-3">News</h1>
        <div className="btns ">
          {Category.map((value, index) => {
            return <CategoryButton category={value} key={index} />;
          })}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="news">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            { 
            !loading 
            ? <SpinnerLoad/>
             :
            state.map((data,index) => {
              return (
                <NewsItem
                  imageUrl={data.imageUrl}
                  author={data.author}
                  title={data.title}
                  content={data.content}
                  date={data.date}
                  key={data.id}
                />
              );
            })
            }
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
export default App;
```

```html
import React from 'react'
import clock from "../components/assets/img/Clock.svg"
import user from "../components/assets/img/User.svg"
const NewsItem = (props) => {

    const {imageUrl, title, content, date, author} = props

    return (
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 p-2">
            <div className="newsItem">
                <img src={imageUrl} alt=''/>
                <div className="itemBody">
                    <p className='title'>{title}</p>
                    <div className="line"></div>
                    <p className='content'>{content}</p>
                    <div className="itemfooter">
                        <h6><img src={clock} alt='clock'/>{date}</h6>
                        <h6><img src={user} alt='user'/>{author}</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default NewsItem
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In react, if you refresh the app , the state values will reinitialise.

From your question , it seems like you want to store the category value and even after refresh , you want to persist the category value..

For that you can store category value in local or sessionStorage..

```
 const fetchValue = (category) => {
  localStorage.setItem("category", category);
  // your code
 }

 // in useEffect , you can check for the category value in the local Storage

useEffect(() => {
// check value in localStorage, if does not exist use "all" as default value
let categoryValue = localStorage.getItem("category") || "all" ;
fetchValue(categoryValue)
},[]);
```